# Javascript stuck in "else"

Tags: javascript, datepicker, datetimepicker, timepicker

I am new in this javascript

so, the store needs this situation in their date time picker

> Open time: **12:00**
>
> Close time: **21:00**

The `minimum` time to **prepare** the order is `+2 hours` from the user visit, and the `maximum` **date** are `+14 days` from **now**.

When the user visits the web in 10:00, the time picker will show 12:00 (open store)
when user visit web in 13:00, the time picker will show 15:00

When a user visits in 13:00 and user select another date (not today) the time picker will show 12:00-21:00 (this is correct)

The problem is when user select today date (without refreshing the page) the time picker will still show 12:00-21:00, it must be 15:00-21:00 range

Heres my code, sorry if lack of language or inform

Here I used date time picker from https://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/time/#events

thanks!

```js
  
                var today = new Date() + 14;
            
            var currentD = new Date();
            var jambuka = new Date();
            jambuka.setHours(12,00,0); // 5.30 pm
            jamsekarang = currentD.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { hour12: false });
            
                var ini;
              $('#tanggal_acara').pickadate({
                  format:'yyyy-mm-dd',
                  min: today,
                  max: +14,
                  hiddenName: true,
                    onSet: function(thingSet) {
                  ini = thingSet;
                  cekin(ini);
                  
                }
                  
              }); 
              
            
              initdate();
            
              function cekin(val)
              {
                  
                   var today = new Date() + 14;
            
                var currentD = new Date();
                var jambuka = new Date();
                jambuka.setHours(12,00,0); // 5.30 pm
                jamsekarang = currentD.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { hour12: false });
                  var tglini = new Date(val.select);
                  var tglnow = new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0));
                  tglini.toString();
            
                  if(val.select == tglnow.getTime())
                  {
                      console.log("sama");
                      if( currentD >= jambuka )
                        {
                        $('#jam_acara').pickatime({
                              format:'HH:i',
                                min: +2,
                                max:'21:00'
                            });
                        }
                        else{
                          
                        $('#jam_acara').pickatime({
                            format:'HH:i',
                                min:'12:00',
                                max:'21:00'
                            });
                        }
                  }
                  else{
                      console.log("beda");
                      var beda;
                      var tglbeda = val.select;
                    //   console.log(tglbeda);
                       $('#jam_acara').pickatime({
                           format:'HH:i',
                                min:'12:00',
                                max:'21:00',
                               
                            });
                        }
                  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr"></script>
            
 <div class="input-simple-2 input-green bottom-10" style="width: 50%; float: left;">
                            <strong class="color-highlight">Tanggal Acara</strong>
                           <input type="text" class="datetimepicker" name="tanggal_acara" required="" id="tanggal_acara">
                        </div>
                        
                   
                        <div class="input-simple-2 input-green bottom-10" style="width: 50%; display:inline-block">
                            <strong class="color-highlight">Jam Acara</strong>
                           <input type="text" class="datetimepicker" name="jam_acara" required id="jam_acara">
                        </div>
```

Comment: I don't see a condition in your if statement for checking if the day/date selected is equal to today's day/date?

Comment: @baarkerlounger hi
its in the line "  if(val.select == tglnow.getTime()) "
thanks

Comment: That's going to include the time in the check though right? Whereas you only want it to compare the date?

Comment: hi @baarkerlounger the check is doing right, but when user chose other date, it just get stuck in the same result, which is in "else" state.
i got it fix with remove and append the element again.

thanks!